# Generic error when executing SQL INSERT in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a simple form that takes some feedback from the user and adds it to a MySQL database.

The code is as follows -

```
<?php

$store_id = '4';
$feedbackcontent = 'test';
$rating = '2';

if($feedbackcontent=='' || $rating=='') {
echo 'Feedback and a rating are required';  
}
else {
$s1 = new MySqlTable();

$sql = 'INSERT INTO reviews (store_id, FeedbackContent, Rating) 
VALUES ("'.$s1->escape($store_id).'", "'.$s1->escape($feedbackcontent).'", "'.$s1->escape($rating).'")';

$s1->executeQuery($sql);
}

?>
```

But, when I run it in Chrome, I get the following error in the debug console.

500 (Internal Server Error)

[Screenshot of the 500 internal server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htq7g.png)

Its worth mentioning If I remove the below lines of code and put a simple echo or something, it works OK.

```
$s1 = new MySqlTable();

$sql = 'INSERT INTO reviews (store_id, FeedbackContent, Rating) 
VALUES ("'.$s1->escape($store_id).'", "'.$s1->escape($feedbackcontent).'", "'.$s1->escape($rating).'")';

$s1->executeQuery($sql);
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with the code or a better way to debug this type of error? Im quite new to PHP, but as far as I can tell this code should work.

Comment: where is the attached error ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya apologies I forgot to attach. Edited.

Comment: This is internal server error. Please check your Apache error logs.

Comment: I guess you're running the PHP embeded server. If so, the real error message will be in the terminal you are running the `php -S` command. Check it out.

Comment: PHP is running on my IIS 7.5 server. Im just trying to find the logs for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss to set connection with database mysql.

```
$mysqli             =   new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "dbname");
```

Comment: I think the connection to the DB is set in another file called Db_connection.php which is referenced in the page. I am showing the feedback from the same database on the same page so I assume its working.

Comment: I stand corrected. There was a typo in the path to this include file!

Comment: Try to set 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);